# Unable to boot a Dell laptop from ubuntu DVD

Tags: dual-boot, dell, intel

When I try to boot the laptop (which already has a Windows 10 installed) from an Ubuntu DVD, it shows the same message given in the question here: [Unable to boot computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664565/unable-to-boot-computer/948346). The only difference is that he had a problem with booting from the hard disk, but I am unable to boot from CD. While the problem in the other question seems to have been with the hard disk, I am pretty sure that the DVDs I tried are good, as I have installed from them recently.

Comment: status please...

Comment: I suspected a hardware problem and reported it to the owner, who talked to the company's customer care people. They requested us to try simply taking out the battery and putting it back. That seemed to work. The machine then booted properly into Windows. On shutting down and starting again, I pressed F12  and chose hard disk, and it booted into Ubuntu. Then I installed refind and it is working properly now. Thanks to everyone who responded.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting PXE boot errors, the boot order is incorrect in your BIOS. It's trying to boot from a network device via PXE.

The Preboot Execution Environment (PXE) is an industry standard client/server interface that allows networked computers that are not yet loaded with an operating system to be configured and booted remotely by an administrator.

Check your BIOS boot order, and it should be set to something like this...

1. CD-ROM
2. HDD/SDD
3. USB
4. PXE

You can also hitting F12 (this key varies by manufacturer) at power on (BIOS display screen), to bring up a manual boot menu, where you could select to boot from the HDD/SSD directly.